# How can I make my shared items in Google Reader publish automatically into Twitter?

Tags: twitter, rss, google-reader

Google Reader's Shared Items published a RSS feed. Can I somehow import that automatically into Twitter, so when I share something in GR it becomes a tweet?

I know there's a Send-To solution, but that's not what I'm looking for.

---

**Edit**

Ok, some googling came up with [Twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com/), which does just that.

Comment: I've tried TwitterFeed and found it to be "hit or miss" most of the time (same for another I've tried - I forgot the name at the moment.)  It would often skip a lot of RSS items. I got fed up and I ended up writing my own program in C# to monitor the feed (it checks every half hour) and post to Twitter as new stuff appears on the feed (it's kind of specific to my feed, however.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to http://www.google.com/reader/shared/[your username]
2. Click on "Atom Feed" and copy the URL
3. Go to [feedburner.google.com](http://feedburner.google.com) and add your feed.
4. Go to "Publicize" → "Socialize" and add a Twitter account
5. Check the formatting options to see how your feed is going to be tweeted

Answer (score 2):

Since items you share also go into your Buzz feed (assuming you haven't disabled them) I would expect you could use the "[BuzzCanTweet](http://www.buzzcantweet.com/)" service to do the same thing.